# React: How can I render multiple menus with map() without causing a re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component called `<SiteMenu />`. Inside of my render function I have these three lines:

```
render() {
    { this.renderPrimaryMenu() }
    { secondaryMenuContents && this.renderSecondaryMenu() }
    { this.renderAdditional() }
}
```

Each of those have a corresponding function that maps through results and creates menus as unordered list. A boiled-down version:

```
renderAdditional() {
    const { secondaryMenuContents } = this.props;
    if (!secondaryMenuContents) { return false; }

    const additional = filter(secondaryMenuContents.sections, { additional: true });
    if (!additional || additional.length === 0) { return false; }

    const links = additional.map(
        (link, index) => {
            return (
                <Link
                    key={ `${index}-${link.link}` }
                    to: link.link
                >
                    { link.text }
                </Link>
            );
        }
    );

    return (
        <nav className={ styles['nav--additional'] }>
            <Responsive>
                <h3 className={ styles.h3 }>{ Lang.additionalSection.title }</h3>
                <menu className={ styles['menu--additional'] }>
                    { links }
                </menu>
            </Responsive>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Each time one of these lists is rendered it re-renders the entire component. One of the menus uses static JSON (`renderPrimaryMenu()`) while the other two depend on data in two separate calls from an API, so that data doesn’t always come in at the same time.

Any suggestions for ensuring a single render OR, even better, having the first static menu (which fades in and re-fades in with every render) display and the other two render when they’re ready *without* causing the first menu to re-render?

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to separate these three components.

And use [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to ensure whether to rerender the component.

This is the pseudo-code:

```
class PrimaryMenu extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // if data is the same, return false
    // else return true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

class SecondaryContent extends Component {
  // same logic as PrimaryMenu
}

class Additional extends Component {
  // same logic as PrimaryMenu
}

class SiteMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PrimaryMenu/>
      <SecondaryContent/>
      <Additional/>
    )
  }
}
```

So with this setup, you can control the re-render time at each `Menu`.

Comment: I‘ll give that a go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

or try PureComponent, it exists to reduce re-rendering stuff.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Additional extends PureComponent {

}
```

More info
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent